# Boost asio TCP + google proto

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, protocol-buffers

I do my first footsteps with boost asio and google proto. I defined a small test message

```
message Test
{
optional string test=1;
optional int32 value=2;
}
```

and one async boost asio server which response with the following function:

```
  void start()
  {
      Test test;
      test.set_test("test");
      test.set_value(44444);
      test.PrintDebugString();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(test.SerializeAsString()),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
```

my test client is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "test.pb.h"


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::endpoint end_point(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 15000);
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.connect(end_point);
    std::string data;

    for (;;)
    {
      boost::array<char, 128> buf;
      boost::system::error_code error;

      size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

      if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
      {
         Test test;
         test.ParseFromString(data);
         test.PrintDebugString();
         break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
      }
      else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

      data.append(buf.begin(), buf.end());

    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If i call my server with my client  a few times i get different outputs:

```
test: "test"
value: 44444
533 {
}

test: "test"
value: 44444
1644{
}

test: "test"
value: 44444
```

the last output is as expected the rest is wrong. I dont understand why i get a bigger output then I have on my server :

```
test: "test"
value: 44444
```

Anyone has an idea why i get something like "1644{ }" ?

I think my eof is wrong or?

### EDIT

```
message Header
{
 required int32 size=1;
}
```

new start

```
  void start()
  {
      boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(m_headerData, m_sizeOfHeader),
                boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read_header, this,
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
```

members:

```
  const size_t m_sizeOfHeader = sizeof(Header::default_instance().SerializeAsString());
  boost::array<char, sizeof(Header::default_instance().SerializeAsString())> m_headerData;



void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& error_code)
{
    if (!error_code)
    {
        Header header;
        header.ParseFromString(std::string(m_headerData.begin(), m_headerData.end()));
        header.PrintDebugString();
    }
    else
    {

        std::cout << error_code.message()<< "ERROR DELETE READ \n";
        delete this;
    }
```

I tried my header on this way now, but i get following errors:

Operation canceled or Bad file descriptor

My new client sends :

```
  Header header;
  header.set_size(101);
  boost::asio::write(socket,boost::asio::buffer(header.SerializeAsString())) ;
```

I think the problem is that the variable m_sizeOfHeader is wrong... on my server side i get 8, and when i print the output of write on client I get 2...

I dont understand why my sizes for the header are not fixed... i just have one required field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring number of bytes read (`len`) and append garbage to `data` with:

```
data.append(buf.begin(), buf.end());
```

try instead:

```
data.append(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + len);
```

Also your code will correctly work only if a single message is sent and socket immediately gracefully closed (with `shutdown`) after that. In more complex scenario you'll need some kind of protocol that allows to determine message bounds. For instance, you can send message size in first two bytes before message and on receiving side first read two bytes with expected message size, then read message body.

Comment: thank you that works great. What is the best pratice for the length prefix? I thought about a header message with just a int32.

Comment: For compact binary representation having just length value in network byte order (`htons`/`htonl`) is ok. But it depends on your needs, you can as well put message inside http request with size defined in content-length header and use it with any http server library.

Comment: I tried to use a header message but I dont know how i can get a fixed buffer and get the right buffer size. I did a edit above

Comment: @Hunk, `sizeof` returns size of c++ object, string has `size` method that returns data size. In general when lost try to add as much debug output as possible - e.g. dump message being sent in hex and its length, same on receiving side and you'll see inconsistencies immediately. also protobuf uses variadic encoding for `int32` type, so your header size is not guaranteed to be the same. better use `fixed32` - it will always be encoded in 4 bytes.

Comment: thank you my headers works now... but i have the problem to get the constant size of my header message on compile time. My message is 
required fixed32 bodySize=1 [default=0]; and i tried 
Header::default_instance().ByteSize() , but i also get Zero. Do u know how i get my size of the header on compile time?